# VB.Net: Read list of files from a text file and check if file exists

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, text, foreach

I want to create a utility in VB.Net that has a basic GUI form that will allow the user to check that a series of files exist.

The GUI is fine and I have no issues with but what i need is help with getting the utility to read the text file (which has no fixed location, just next to where ever the exe is run from) and then for each line check that the file exsists in a predetermined path.

```
Dim path, file, nextLine  as String
path = "C:\ProgramName\Folder\
file = path & 'nextLine of text file
```

The text file would be simple and just be like the following.

```
setup.exe
file.ext
file2.ext
etc...
```

I can get it to check the file exists fine,once the file is in the variable but I am not sure how to get it to go through each one check it exsists or not. I am think a FOR EACH or a LOOP but am not sure, the same for the location of the text file (Ideally I want it to be next to the exe, but the exe has no fixed path and can move dependent on loctaion. Is anyone able to help.

Edit the txt file would look like...

```
filename1.ext
filename2.ext
filename3.ext
```

So i would manually set in a text box using a folder browser the path it is looking too e.g. "C:\Temp\filelist.txt" then manually set in another one the directory to serach to see if it exists e.g. C:\Temp\Files\ and store those in variables and then for each line in the text file see if it exist in the path.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the files you are looking for are in the same path;

```
    Dim fileList As String
    Dim fileName As String
    fileList = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\temp\fileList.txt")
    For X = 0 To fileList.Split(vbCrLf).Count - 1
        fileName = fileList.Split(vbCrLf).ElementAt(X).ToString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("c:\temp\" & fileName) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName) 'add items to this list if they exist
        Else
            ListBox2.Items.Add(fileName) 'add items to this list if they do not exist
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: That does not work it says count and elementAt are not part of System.Array ?

Comment: This works, I wrote and tested it before I posted it.
But I made my own txt file and the TXT file contained file name and a CRLF on each line.  So in order to help you further I will need more information from you.

Comment: Hi thanks, ok i am using Visual Studio 2012 and rest of the details have been edited into the main post - Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-liner to check if a file exists.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(file_path_to_check)
```